# Library/Framework for generating Contract Forms

Tags: abi

Based on ABI, Mist is able to automatically generate forms for contracts for read/write access.

Does someone know if there is a JS framework/library for this task? For the prototyping/demonstration purpose, it’s extremely useful to be able to quickly generate corresponding forms.